# Delete in array Java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I have that function where i want the user to pick a number of all schedules to delete one.
My logic for delete is to find the `i` that I want to delete and then swap the last one schedule of my array with the `i` one, and then the last one to be null.

When i test my program i see that when I want to delete the last one of my array everything works ok, but when i try to delete something else an error shows up in eclipse.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
I cant figure out what's happening. I have reviewed my code a lot of times.

```
 public void ScheduleDelete(){
    StandardInputRead readDeleteSchedule = new StandardInputRead();

    int deleteScheduleNum =readDeleteSchedule.readPositiveInt("Enter the schedule number you want to delete: ");
    for(int i=0;i<scheduleSize;i++){
        if(deleteScheduleNum==this.scheduleList[i].getScheduleNum()){
            this.scheduleList[i]= this.scheduleList[this.scheduleSize-1];
            this.scheduleList[i].setScheduleNum(i);
            this.scheduleList[this.scheduleSize-1]= null;
        }
    }
    this.scheduleSize--;
}
```

Comment: I have the feeling that you're reinventing java.util.ArrayList.

Comment: It will be much simpler and more readable to use a List instead of an Array.

Comment: Yeah I know but I come from C and I would like to practice first on methods classes etc and when I understand them well I will try ArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you swap the element with the last one the second time, you will replace the element with `null` (as you have just set the last element of the array to `null` in the previous swap).  So when you want to use the element, you are operating on a null reference, hence the exception.

You need to keep track of how many *active* element you have in the array and swap the element with the last *active* one.

Alternatively, you can use a dynamic collection (e.g. a list) where you don't need to excplicitly keep track of the active elements because you only store the active ones.

Comment: So you say that the item that I try to swap(last one) is already null?

Comment: Actually, I think I got it wrong, you _do_ decrement the active object counter (`scheduleSize`).  Is it possible that more than one element returns the same value for `getScheduleNum()` as `deleteScheduleNum`?  Also, am I correct that the schedule number is equivalent to `i`?  If yes, you could just access the `i`th elemement directly, no need to loop through the array

Comment: you're right. I found my mistake. I did this and my code worked perfect!!! Selected answer!!